# Monitoring last rsync backup

Tags: linux, cron, freebsd, rsync

I am backing up my notebook running Arch and my girlfriend's MacBook regularly using `rsync` and `cron` / `launchctl` via `ssh`.
The target is a FreeNAS server.

I would like to monitor whether the automatic jobs are running correctly, by receiving a notification if the content of the backup folders did not change for a certain time. How can I do that? Or is there some other approach usually used to verify that automatic jobs are running?

Comment: Couple of ideas.  Your `cron` job that runs the backup can email upon success and/or failure.  You could set a `cron` job on the NAS that looks at the backup file tree and emails if it does not see anything newer than _n_ days old (`find /backups/ -mtime [...] || echo "" |  mail -s "no backups on $(date)" yourself@example.com`)

Comment: In principle a nice idea and exactly what I asked for. Didn't know about the mtime switch. However, executing the command takes ages when I search the whole backup directory. Maybe it suffices if I just look at the change time in certain folders like /var/tmp. Anyway, I will have a look into that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The content of the backup not changing as a symptom of the backup not running? In that case monitor the cronjob with a dedicated cron monitor such as [WDT.io](https://wdt.io). This [recipe's example](https://cookbook.wdt.io/cron.html) is specifically about backups and shows you how to do it.

Comment: Nice idea. I'm not too comfortable, though, with using an external service (any security concerns, etc?). I will think and read about it, thanks for the idea!

Comment: After some evaluation it seems as if a cronjob monitoring serves me better than monitoring the file changes. Thanks again for the suggestion.